# Remove Decimal form String if equals to ".00"

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Im having alot of problems trying to take out the decimal part of my string,
the string comes from a **var type** in my view like this:

```
 var temp = dashList[index];
  @PrintSection(actualDate, Model, String.Format("{0:0.000}", temp.Rubro))**
```

temp.Rubro is my String part that can be **".00"** or **".XX"**

however i need to take the decimal part of the string only when its value is **".00"**
since i have some values of the dashlist have important decimal parts.

Is there a way to take the decimal part of a string only if it equals to **".00"**???

The output im trying to get is:

```
From XX.00 -> XX
From XX.12 -> XX.12
```

both kinds are on my list

Comment: There is no such thing as a "var" type in C#. The compiler is merely being nice to you and recognizes that you're declaring a `string`.

Comment: A simple `Replace` should do the work, that's most havind a decimal value in a string the "problem" in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var temp = dashList[index];
@PrintSection(actualDate, Model, String.Format("{0:0.000}", temp.Rubro).Replace(".00", ""))
```

Comment: tryed this but the result is still the same, .00 for all values

Comment: @ArturoMartinez - I can see one issue, but that shouldn't affect the result in the way you're saying. The `{0:0.000}` has three zeroes after the decimal point so the replace should be `.Replace(".000", "")`. However this doesn't sound like the problem you're having. Nevertheless I have tested this answer and it worked for me.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez - Try this: `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", 14).Replace(".00", ""));`. It produces `14` to the console for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
String.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse(temp.Rubro)))
```

Whereas all the below formats achieve the same results.

```
string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse("2.00"))
decimal.Parse("2.00").ToString("G29")
2.0m.ToString("G29")
```

You can use `ToString()` with the `General ("G") Format Specifier` to achieve the desired result. Trailing zeros are truncated when using this format string with a precision specified. In order to prevent rounding in any situations, you will need to set the precision to the maximum allowed for decimals (29).

Comment: i tryed this solution but it trows me a System.FormatException

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick...

You can parse the string and it will automatically remove the decimal places 
try following

```
 private static void ParseDouble()
    {
        string sDouble = "12.00";
        double dValue = double.Parse(sDouble);
        Console.WriteLine(dValue.ToString());


        sDouble = "12.14";
        dValue = double.Parse(sDouble);
        Console.WriteLine(dValue.ToString());
    }
```

Your output will be

```
12
12.14
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tryed your method but it trows me a System.FormatException

Comment: Could you post the exact input string?

Comment: probably something related to culture and decimal separator

Comment: the string is maked froma  list, and the results of each vary but they are like : 233293.8900 or 20.00

Comment: Both the values worked for me and gave me following output 20 &
233293.89

Comment: You will get System.FormatException when this "temp.Rubro" will have a value which is not number.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [accounting.js](https://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/) plugging which is pretty straightforward. I have used it in some projects and as of today I cannot complain. Otherwise, you could do something like this,

```
var x = temp.Replace(".00","").Trim();
```